# how to identify jobs running background on Windows 7-10？

Tags: python, windows, powershell, windows-7

I want to run a Python process in background, and  I use the following command in PowerShell.

`powershell > PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden python my_process.py`

But, How can I know whether it is running in background? The task manager can not show a process named `python my_process.py` that running in background, and I don't know the process id on task manager, it just show some `python` and `powershell` processes running in background. I can not identify which process is my Python process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not actually a programming question, but:

In Task Manager's Process page, choose **View > Select Columns** and add the Command Line column. Then you can see the actual command line for each process and you should be able to track down the ones you're interested in.

This is for Windows 7; I know they made some changes to the Task Manager for Windows 10 but don't have access to a Windows 10 machine at the moment.

Comment: Note in Windows 10, you go to the Details page of the Task manager and right-click a column header to configure which columns are displayed.